# rails 3 establish_connection doesn't work for switching databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I need to use two different db in my app.  I found a simple example:

http://pullmonkey.com/2008/4/21/ruby-on-rails-multiple-database-connections/

using establish_connection, but it doesn't seem to work.  To test switching databases, I have:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :test
    # attr_accessible :title, :body
  end
```

But I get the error:  "Uncaught exception: database configuration does not specify adapter".

Here is my database.yaml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: foo
  username: bar
  host: foo.com
  password: foobar

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I am running in development mode for this test. Any ideas why it can't switch?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, I've figured out that User.establish_connection :test called from the controller will work.  I would like to call it from inside the User class file.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

First the "pulmonkeyexample" is to use a database label when you have multiple databases and other than the three standard ones - "development, test and production". When you start a rails application, you can use "-e" option to tell rails which mode to start the application in -  test, dev or prod. Depending on the mode in which the app is starting, Rails will automatically use corresponding database connections from the "database.yml" file. So remove that line from your model. On second thoughts, even if you write yet it should work provided there is a test database with the user table.